# magento invoice pdf header on every pdf pages

Tags: php, html, magento, pdf

In magento default invoice is printed in pdf format, I have set logo and address in my header part of pdf from magento admin. after exporting PDF, if that is in multiple pages I found that logo and address is not being printed on every pages.

can anyone let me how to print logo and address on every pages. same I want for footer part also.
for footer part I have applied 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99506/add-to-footer-image-in-adminpage-pdf-invoice

I have tried to customize file 
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
and here is the out put of PDF.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Done this by adding draw header code into

```
public function newPage(array $settings = array())
{
    /* Add new table head */
    $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
    $this->y = 800;
    if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
        $this->insertLogo($page); // added by me
        $this->insertAddress($page); // added by me
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
    }
    return $page;
}
```